# How to create a program that displays the process of different threads using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to Threads in C# and I want to learn it. I'm having a difficult time creating a program where different processes of threads are being outputted to the console. I use Visual Studio 2019 as my IDE, and Windows Form (.NET Framework).

In my program, I have one windows form named MyForm with a button named 'Activate', and a label that says 'Starts'. When I click the button, I want to create a loop that terminates the thread in the fifth attempt. The current thread should be suspended for about 3 seconds.

This is my code in Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Threading
{
   public partial class MyForm : Form
   {
       public MyForm()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           Thread XThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
           Thread YThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
       }
   }

   private void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   public class TClass
   {
       public static void FirstThread()
       {
           for(int i = 0; i >= 5; i++)
           {
               Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
               Console.WriteLine(thread.Name + " = " + i);

               Thread.Sleep(3000);
               thread.Abort();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

In the code above, I have created two threads named XThread and YThread in the MyForm class. I am not sure if I did it right though.

I am also wondering if I need to use a Join method to stop calling a thread until the thread is terminated.

This is what I am expecting to be outputted to the console:

```
--Start--
Thread X Process = 0
Thread Y Process = 0
Thread Y Process = 1
Thread X Process = 1
Thread Y Process = 2
Thread X Process = 2
Thread X Process = 3
Thread Y Process = 3
Thread Y Process = 4
Thread X Process = 4
Thread X Process = 5
Thread Y Process = 5
The thread has exited with code 0
The thread has exited with code 0
--Finish--
```

After the output in the console is complete, I want the label in my windows form to be changed from 'Start' to 'Finish'.

I know I'm missing some code here, and I don't know what to do next. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: *"I want to create a loop that terminates the thread"* <== What thread, the UI thread? If you kill the UI thread, you are killing the application.

Comment: _"In the code above, I have created two threads"_ - No you haven't. You created two references to the UI Thread.

Comment: `thread.Abort();` - Forget that you know this method exists. Never use it. Unless you know _exactly_ what you are doing and that there is no other way than calling it. And then find a another way.

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is only ever useful if you are trying to forcibly crash out of your app. It should never ever ever be used at any other time. It can leave the run-time in a corrupted state and you can't rely on any remaining thread to be valid.

Comment: In any case your code is incomplete. Please provide a [mcve] of what you have now.